# Exclude an object from colliding

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, collision

I have a collision between a block falling from above and a moving cube on the floor. The problem is that whenever I do cube:addEventListener("collision", onCollision), the cube hits the floor and corona thinks that that is the collision. The same goes with block:addEventListener. Because of the fact that the cube is moving, the block doesn't always hit the cube but it hits the floor and corona detects a collision.

I also have a loop going on to spawn the blocks. Is there a way to disable this loop when the collision happens, as it keeps spawning the blocks.

This is the code I have:

```
function blockremove()
display.remove( block )
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, blockspawn)
end

function collision(event)
if(event.phase == "began") then
    display.remove( cube )
    display.remove( block )
    gameover = display.newText( "Game Over", display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, native.systemFontBold, 36 )
    gameover:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )
end
 end


 function blockspawn()
 block = display.newRect( 0, 0, 50, 50 )
 block:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )
 block.x = math.random(50, display.contentWidth -50 )
 block.y = -50
 physics.addBody( block, {density=50, friction=0, bounce=0.3} )
 timer.performWithDelay( 3000, blockremove )
 block:addEventListener( "collision", collision )
 end
```

Comment: You saying you have multiple collisions possible (block-floor, cube-floor, block-cube) and can't find a way to distinguish between them? Not clear what the question is. Also I suggest you keep questions separate on SO, seems to me the "disable the loop" question is completely distinct from first one.

Comment: Yes, that is another question, I will try not to ask two questions in the same post again, and yes I have 3 objects: a floor, a cube that moves on the floor and a block falling from the air, I want the game to end when the block falls on the cube, but I want it to continue when it falls on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution for this is

in onCollision function you identify the object block collided with & perform actions accordingly.

You can identify the object using

event.object1.myName 
event.object2.myName

```
if event.object2.myName ~= "floor" then

   -- do what you want here
else
    --do nothing

end
```

Note: You will first name the object
eg.

floor.myName="floor"

http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection
Please reply or vote me up am block here.

Comment: Whenever I try to do this: ground.myName = "ground"
function collision(event)
 if event.object2.myName ~= "ground" then
  display.remove( cube )
  display.remove( block )
  gameover = display.newText( "Game Over", display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, native.systemFontBold, 36 )
  gameover:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )
 end
end  IT doesn't seem to work I get the error: Attempt to set nil value to object2

Comment: try this if cube~=nil then remove it & nil.

Comment: remember it only remove what you see i.e. visual part but the physical body of the same will remain in the memory you also need to remove that.

Comment: Aah! I caught the problem

Answer (score 1):

When an object collide with other object you see that it's calling collision function, but it calls that several times, so when first time it is called it removed the object but next time it is trying to clean an object that is already clean.

always remove the object safely.

if object~= nil then

```
--remove
```

end

Comment: Hmm, well this solved the error I was getting but now the same happens again: When the block hits the floor it detects a collision. Am I doing this right: function collision(event)
  if cube ~= nil and block ~= nil then
  display.remove( cube )
  cube = nil
  display.remove( block )
  block = nil
  gameover = display.newText( "Game Over", display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, native.systemFontBold, 36 )
  gameover:setFillColor( 1,0,0 )
 
 end

Comment: if event.object2.myName ~= "floor" then

  if cube ~= nil and block ~= nil then display.remove( cube ) cube =    nil 
else
    --do nothing

end

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK supports the concept of Collision filters where you can define which objects interact with which.

See: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#filtering

Answer (score 0):

```
   if event.object2.myName ~= "floor" then
       if cube ~= nil and block ~= nil then 
            display.remove( cube ) 
            cube =nil end
       end
    end
```

First put a condition that object collided with should be not floor, if it fulfils the condition, then it should also pass one another test that it should not already removed.